# JQueryMobile form always empty

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to do a simple JQM AJAX form post to a server - but for some reason, my form input values are *always* empty. (Even in the DOM inspector)
This is the 2nd page in my HTML - and the only form on the page. The console always prints out "[]"

```
<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>
            Login
        </h2>
        <form id="loginform" data-ajax="false">
            <fieldset>
                <input name="" id="userId" name="userId" placeholder="login" type="number">
                <input name="" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" type="password">
                <input type="button" id="login_submit" data-theme="b" value="Submit">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script language="JavaScript" >
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#login", function(){
            $(document).on('click', '#login_submit', function() {
                console.debug($('#loginform').serializeArray());
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is obvious once it's posted into SO.
There's duplicate name attributes on the input fields - note the original issue was probably that the name attributes were set as "" - which would drop them from the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#loginform', function() {
     console.debug($('#loginform').serializeArray());
});
```